# Best way to create a list of objects?

Tags: python, class, oop

`food_data` is a variable containing JSON data. Using the data, I want to create a list of Food objects, like so

```
foods = []
for data_row in food_data:
    foods.append(Food(data_row))
```

This is what my Food class looks like as of right now:

```
class Food(dict):
    """ by inheriting from dict, Food objects become automatically serializable for JSON formatting """

    def __init__(self, data):
        """ create a serialized food object with desired fields """
        id = data["id"]
        name = data["title"]
        image = data["image"]

        super().__init__(self, id=id, name=name, image=image)
```

And here is some example data:

```
[
        {
            "id": 738290,
            "title": "Pasta with Garlic, Scallions, Cauliflower & Breadcrumbs",
            "image": "https://spoonacular.com/recipeImages/716429-312x231.jpg",
        },
        {
            "id": 343245,
            "title": "What to make for dinner tonight?? Bruschetta Style Pork & Pasta",
            "image": "https://spoonacular.com/recipeImages/715538-312x231.jpg",
        }
]
```

**Is there a method I can write for the Food class that will take the data and return a list of different versions of itself?**

Comment: Yes it’s possible. You’re gonna need to show the data your working with if you want a more detailed answer

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. You are creating a list of `Food` objects. What is the problem?

Comment: What do you mean by "different versions of itself"?

Comment: @juanpa im looking for a more efficient/ scalable way of rewriting the code.

Comment: instead of `Food(data_row)` you probably want `Food(**data_row)`

Comment: @Wizard what is inefficient or unscalable about what you've wrote? It seems perfectly acceptable to me. It scales linearly, which is the best you can hope for.

Comment: @rv.kvetch My only concern there would be the overhead of unpacking a large `dict` that might contain more keys than `Food.__init__` cares about. But I do agree that `__init__` should take three specific arguments rather than a `dict`. Let a class method like `Food.from_dict` take an arbitrary `dict`, extract the three keys it cares about, and pass them to `Food`.

Comment: @juanpa, I created another function which uses this exact same block of code, I feel like there must be a way of shortening the code

Comment: @Wizard so you *don't* care about scalability or efficiency? You just care about the lines of code? Well just use a list comprehension. But your question needs to be specific.

Comment: There are, however, issues with overriding `__init__` in a way that isn't otherwise compatible with `dict.__init__`.

Comment: I also wouldn't subclass `dict` just to piggyback on its serializability. You can define a custom encoder by subclassing `json.JSONEncoder` to teach `json` how to serialize an instance of `Food`.

Comment: You could create a static method in the class. This method would contain the code you presented for crating the list. Use `food_data` as a parameter and return the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would start by *not* subclassing `dict`: there is a better way to make an instance of `Food` serializable.

Next, make `Food.__init__` dumb: three arguments, used to set three attributes.

Then, define a class method that is responsible for parsing an arbitrary `dict` with at least `id`, `title`, and `image` keys to get the values expected by `Food.__init__`.

Finally, define a method that turns an instance of `Food` back into a `dict` (though not necessarily the same `dict` that `from_dict` uses; generate one that serializes the way you want).

```
class Food:
    def __init__(self, id, name, image):
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.image = image

    @classmethod
    def from_dict(cls, d):
        return cls(id=d['id'], name=d['title'], image=d['image'])

    def to_dict(self):
        return dict(id=self.id, name=self.name, image=self.image)

foods = [Food.from_dict(d) for d in food_data]
```

To make your instance serializable, define a customer encoder that uses your `to_dict` method,

```
class FoodEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, Food):
            return obj.to_dict()
        return super().default(obj)
```

This piggy backs on the default encoder; if the immediate object is a `Food`, `default` returns a serializable `dict`. Otherwise, it defers to its parent to try to serialize it.

Then use that class in the call to `json.dumps`.

```
print(json.dumps(foods, cls=FoodEncoder))
```

Comment: I appreciate you optimizing a portion of my code that I was also unsure on but didn't question. Will implement now

Answer (score 0):

I think in my case I may have been over-engineering my code. But I received many responses that did help me out in other aspects so I'm going to offer them here:

@Juanpa
Use a list comprehension

```
foods = [Food[data] for data in food_data]
```

@Chepner - unrelated but useful
subclass json.JSONEncoder instead of dict for serializability

@Matthias
Create a staticmethod within the class to return a list of objects

```
@staticmethod
def create_foods(food_data):
    foods = []
    for data_row in food_data:
        foods.append(Food(data_row))
```

Comment: With the static method you could also use a list comprehension. Then the body of the function would be just one line: `return [Food[data] for data in food_data]`.

Comment: i ended up doing that exactly and it turns out to be alot more readable, exactly the way I was going for thank you!